# Tag feed not sorted by tagging time

Tags: instagram

The Instagram developer docs say [this](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) about the `/tags/<tag_name>/media/recent` feed:

> Note that this media is ordered by when the media was tagged with this tag, rather than the order it was posted.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case in practice. If I request the data for a tag which is used in a mixture of captions and comments, and then extract the time the relevant caption/comment was posted, I get this:

```
[('caption  ', '2015-04-10 07:55:48'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-10 07:46:31'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-08 17:16:38'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-07 12:20:02'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-07 05:35:47'),
 ('comment 5', '2015-04-11 01:53:33'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-04 15:27:32'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-04 14:11:27'),
 ('comment 0', '2015-04-06 00:49:15'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-04 01:16:52'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-03 23:47:48'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-03 23:45:02'),
 ('comment 2', '2015-04-03 18:48:37'),
 ('comment 0', '2015-04-03 07:35:28'),
 ('comment 1', '2015-04-06 16:11:31'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-02 05:38:34'),
 ('comment 0', '2015-04-04 19:57:26'),
 ('comment 5', '2015-04-02 01:05:38'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-01 15:51:37'),
 ('caption  ', '2015-04-01 15:47:50')]
```

You can clearly see that this data is out of order: items are appearing in order of posting, even when the tag that triggered the update was added in a later comment.

This ordering is vital, as for incomprehensible reasons the real-time tag notification does not include the ID of the media item that has been tagged, meaning we have to then request the recent tagged feed to get that information. If we can't rely on the ordering, there's no way to reliably extract the items that have been tagged without re-parsing the *entire* tag stream every single time, which is clearly unscalable.

Any ideas, or advice on how to get the real ordering by tagging time?

It shouldn't be relevant, but here's the Python code I used to extract the ordering above:

```
def get_date(timestamp):
  return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(timestamp))

def tagged_time(tag):
  url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag_name}/media/recent?client_id={client_id}'
  data = requests.get(url.format(tag_name=tag, client_id=my_client_id)).json()
  times = []
  for item in data['data']:
    if tag in item['caption']['text'].lower():
      times.append(('caption  ', item['caption']['created_time']))
    else:
      for i, c in enumerate(item['comments']['data']):
        if tag in c['text'].lower():
          times.append(('comment %s' % i, get_date(c['created_time'])))
          break
      else:
        times.append('not found')
  return times
```

Comment: Exactly. I am also facing the same which has started happening recently. It was working as expected earlier, though. :/

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is outdated, Instagram recently made a change and they now sort by when the photo was posted, not by when the hashtag was added.

Here is the announcement made by Instagram:
https://twitter.com/instagram/status/581493922620309504

Comment: This talks about the tag pages. Do we know for sure that the API change was an intended result of that?